Shopify Infinite scroll using Ajaxinate stops working after applying the filters
    {% if template contains 'collection' %}
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var endlessScroll = new Ajaxinate({
      container: '#product-grid',
      pagination: '#Huratips-Pagination',
      loadingText: `<div class="loading" style="text-transform: uppercase; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 40px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
              <span style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; display: inline-block; background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0691/4221/6959/files/loader-black.svg?v=1712406692);"></span>
              <span>Loading more products</span>
            </div>`
    });
  });
</script>
{% endif %}

I have written this code for infinite scrolling on my shopify store, but this code stops working after applying the sorting or filter, May be i think it's due to when we apply the sorting or filtering in shopify it reloads the content under the class .product-grid-container and replace the whole html that's why #product-grid and it's content comes as new, due to this it stops working after applying sorting or filtering, is there any way to handle this situation?

in this picture i have shown that reloads whole content under .product-grid-container .collection, i am using spotlight theme in shopify.
thanks in advance for the help.. :)

I was dealing with this issue as well but couldn't make Ajaxinate work. I found a more recent infinite scroll tutorial online and ended up going in a different direction.
The tutorial that I found involved creating a native web component called infinite-scroll and then using the browser's Intersection Observer as well as DOM Parser to add new content to the screen.
So essentially the logic would look something like this:

Create and register the infinite-scroll component
In the constructor set up Intersection Observer to watch it
As part of the callback for Intersection Observer, use a Fetch Request to get the HTML to render the next "page" of products in the collection and use DOM Parser to take the new products and add it into the DOM

This all works well but then the next issue was getting this to work with the collection filter code that is present in most Shopify Themes.
In the Shopify Dawn theme, the filters work by adding a query param to the current page's url and then updating the DOM in response to whatever products would be present on that page (also using DOM Parser).
This would cause the Infinite Scroll component to stop working.
And in order to deal with that problem, I used the browser's Mutation Observer to check for when there is a change in the web component used to create the collection filters.
Whenever there is a change to, I would delete the infinite-scroll component from the DOM and use JavaScript to create a new instance of it and re-insert it into the DOM.
Hope this helps someone else.
By the way here is a link to tutorial that I mentioned above:
How to Add Infinite Scroll to Shopify Collection Page
You can use the code in the tutorial as a starting point.
